# Test redux actions that calls an API

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux, redux-thunk

What is the best way to test this function

```
export function receivingItems() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    axios.get('/api/items')
      .then(function(response) {
        dispatch(receivedItems(response.data));
      });
  };
}
```

this is currently what I have

```
describe('Items Action Creator', () => {
  it('should create a receiving items function', () => {
    expect(receivingItems()).to.be.a.function;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From Redux [“Writing Tests”](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html#async-action-creators) recipe:

> For async action creators using [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or other middleware, it’s best to completely mock the Redux store for tests. You can still use `applyMiddleware()` with a mock store, as shown below (you can find the following code in [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store)). You can also use [nock](https://github.com/pgte/nock) to mock the HTTP requests.
>
> ```
> function fetchTodosRequest() {
>   return {
>     type: FETCH_TODOS_REQUEST
>   }
> }
>
> function fetchTodosSuccess(body) {
>   return {
>     type: FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS,
>     body
>   }
> }
>
> function fetchTodosFailure(ex) {
>   return {
>     type: FETCH_TODOS_FAILURE,
>     ex
>   }
> }
>
> export function fetchTodos() {
>   return dispatch => {
>     dispatch(fetchTodosRequest())
>     return fetch('http://example.com/todos')
>       .then(res => res.json())
>       .then(json => dispatch(fetchTodosSuccess(json.body)))
>       .catch(ex => dispatch(fetchTodosFailure(ex)))
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> can be tested like:
>
> ```
> import expect from 'expect'
> import { applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
> import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
> import * as actions from '../../actions/counter'
> import * as types from '../../constants/ActionTypes'
> import nock from 'nock'
>
> const middlewares = [ thunk ]
>
> /**
>  * Creates a mock of Redux store with middleware.
>  */
> function mockStore(getState, expectedActions, done) {
>   if (!Array.isArray(expectedActions)) {
>     throw new Error('expectedActions should be an array of expected actions.')
>   }
>   if (typeof done !== 'undefined' && typeof done !== 'function') {
>     throw new Error('done should either be undefined or function.')
>   }
>
>   function mockStoreWithoutMiddleware() {
>     return {
>       getState() {
>         return typeof getState === 'function' ?
>           getState() :
>           getState
>       },
>
>       dispatch(action) {
>         const expectedAction = expectedActions.shift()
>
>         try {
>           expect(action).toEqual(expectedAction)
>           if (done && !expectedActions.length) {
>             done()
>           }
>           return action
>         } catch (e) {
>           done(e)
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
>
>   const mockStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
>     ...middlewares
>   )(mockStoreWithoutMiddleware)
>
>   return mockStoreWithMiddleware()
> }
>
> describe('async actions', () => {
>   afterEach(() => {
>     nock.cleanAll()
>   })
>
>   it('creates FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS when fetching todos has been done', (done) => {
>     nock('http://example.com/')
>       .get('/todos')
>       .reply(200, { todos: ['do something'] })
>
>     const expectedActions = [
>       { type: types.FETCH_TODOS_REQUEST },
>       { type: types.FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS, body: { todos: ['do something']  } }
>     ]
>     const store = mockStore({ todos: [] }, expectedActions, done)
>     store.dispatch(actions.fetchTodos())
>   })
> })
> ```

Comment: Also keep in mind this `createMockStore` has been published as a package: https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store

Comment: You can test async actions synchronously using  https://github.com/wix/redux-testkit

Comment: Hi, what if the action being tested is `getTodos` and the returned data is a huge list of todos? how do you mock that scenario?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a stub `axios` (for example by using [mock-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-require)) and write a test that actually calls `receivingItems()(dispatch, getState)` and makes sure `dispatch` is called with the correct data.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this in a different way: injecting axios as a dependency of action. I prefer this approach over 'rewiring' dependencies.

So I used the same approach of testing redux-connected components. When I export actions I export two versions: one with (to be used for components) and one without (for testing) binding dependencies.

Here is how my actions.js file looks like:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const loadDataRequest = () => {
  return {
    type: 'LOAD_DATA_REQUEST'
  }
}
export const loadDataError = () => {
  return {
    type: 'LOAD_DATA_ERROR'
  }
}
export const loadDataSuccess = (data) =>{
  return {
    type: 'LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS',
    data
  }
}
export const loadData = (axios) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(loadDataRequest())
    axios
      .get('http://httpbin.org/ip')
      .then(({data})=> dispatch(loadDataSuccess(data)))
      .catch(()=> dispatch(loadDataError()))
  }
}
export default {
  loadData: loadData.bind(null, axios)
}
```

Then testing with [jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) (actions.test.js):

```
import { loadData } from './actions'

describe('testing loadData', ()=>{
  test('loadData with success', (done)=>{

    const get = jest.fn()
    const data = {
      mydata: { test: 1 }
    }
    get.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({data}))

    let callNumber = 0
    const dispatch = jest.fn(params =>{
      if (callNumber===0){
        expect(params).toEqual({ type: 'LOAD_DATA_REQUEST' })
      }
      if (callNumber===1){
        expect(params).toEqual({
          type: 'LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS',
          data: data
        })
        done()
      }
      callNumber++
    })
    const axiosMock = {
      get
    }
    loadData(axiosMock)(dispatch)
  })
})
```

When using the actions inside a component I import everything:

`import Actions from './actions'`

And to dispatch:

`Actions.loadData() // this is the version with axios binded.`